# terminal script to search CSV file

Tags: command-line, unix

2 parts to this, can't see where I'm going wrong

The 1st part works--get my BSSID through the airport command:

```
myBSSID="/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I | grep BSSID | awk '{print $2}'"
```

then (this is where I get EOF or syntax errors): 
pass that value to awk, which will search a file (APtable.csv) for that string, and give me the adjacent value to it:

```
awk -v theBSSID=$myBSSID '$1 == theBSSID {print $2}' '/Users/russell/Desktop/APtable.csv'
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve in the end, you could also look into doing this in python; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15170342/565489) provides a starting point, and you could easily store (access) the return values using e.g. the `pandas` module in python.

Comment: I've updated my answer, so you might want to review it.

Comment: : (
Spoke too soon.

Comment: So, Murphy's Law, first BSSID I connect to has a leading 0, so the original script doesn't return anything.
But running your addended script does get me something, but I'm not quite sure what:
`awk: newline in string 94:b4:0f:ed:fd:b1
40... at source line 1`

Comment: It seems like awk finds what its looking for in column 1 of the file, but then doesn't print column 2 next to it.

Comment: After a week of puzzling over this and getting nowhere, I'm wondering if anyone has a suggestion on how I can get a log of the script's events. 
In the second part of the script, when it searches for the value adjacent to the BSSID string, it seems to not understand that I want that value (the adjacent one) returned.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to pipe to `grep` and then to `awk` in the first line as `awk` can do what's needed by itself. Also the way you have the first line written, it is missing the `$(...)` around the commands.

In the second line you're missing the field separator in the `awk` command, which in a `.csv` file normally is a comma. So I added that to the `awk` command.

Use the following two lines:

```
myBSSID="$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I | awk '/BSSID/{print $2}')"
awk -F ',' -v theBSSID="$myBSSID" '$1 == theBSSID {print $2}' "$HOME/Desktop/APtable.csv"
```

---

I noticed the output of the `airport` command didn't report the `BSSID` correctly in that if left out some zeros.

If that's the case on your system and the `.cvs` file has proper info, then try the following:

```
myBSSID="$(system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/BSSID/{print $2}')"
awk -F ',' -v theBSSID="$myBSSID" '$1 == theBSSID {print $2}' "$HOME/Desktop/APtable.csv"
```

Note that `system_profiler SPAirPortDataType` isn't as fast as using `airport` but if the output of `airport` is dropping some of the zeros, then you'll need an alternative if the `BSSID`'s in the `.cvs` file have all 12 characters, not counting the colons, which they should.

The following could be used to incorporate both methods in a `bash` *script* so as to only use the second method if the length of `myBSSID` is less then 17 characters, as 17 is the correct length.

```
#!/bin/bash

myBSSID="$(/S*/L*/P*/A*/V*/A/R*/airport -I | awk '/BSSID/{print $2}')"
l="${#myBSSID}"
if [[ $l -lt 17 ]]; then
    myBSSID="$(system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/BSSID/{print $2}')"
fi
awk -F ',' -v theBSSID="$myBSSID" '$1 == theBSSID {print $2}' "$HOME/Desktop/APtable.csv"
```

Comment: 343--
I've noticed that too, (dropping of 0's)... weird. Can we be the first to notice this?
But the important thing is, you got the code to work (together)! Thanks.